# How to add slider on product page Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

- Not continuous slider
- By clicking ‘Next’ and ‘Prev’ arrowheads, only 1 product  will show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slick slider this link might help[enter link description here](http://glivera-team.github.io/shopify/2018/05/10/spotify-slick-slider.en.html)